# How does Django name the index automatically created for foreign keys columns?

Tags: mysql, django

I know that Django automatically generates indexes for foreign keys unless we define the field with `db_index=False`.
I have read it in [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

But I don't know if it is possible to choose the index name, or how django chooses it.

It's always something like "tablename_xxxxxx".

"xxxxx" are like random characters?

**EDITED:**
I've discovered that "xxxx" is some codification from the model field name, but I still don't know whether we can choose an explicit name

Comment: is the xxx part something like _ibfk_1?

Comment: In my real case the full index name is tablename_dbaea34e, but these characters have no sense for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to choose the name of the index. It's actually dynamically computed and it implies the hash of the table name and the column names.

See for instance the [code source here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7901eccf2e591447850be00011a7bb556a3c53f2/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L801), even though it's for a particular version of Django, I'm not aware of any changes towards a user named index.

Comment: Knowing is not easily possible I can spend my time looking for another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to choose the index name? yes but there isn't any benefit in doing so.

The first step is to switch off the [constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.db_constraint), then you need to manually add one into the migration in the form of a migrations.RunSQL
yes, it's a lot of hard work and totally not worth doing.

Comment: I didn't thought of this solution, but you are totally right that is too much hard work. The point is that I renamed a FK after creating it, then I added another FK which had (fortuitously) the same name that de old one, and Django was trying to create an index that was already created. Obviously is a remote case, and it has other solutions, but I was curious. +1

Comment: Unless Django has an undocumented way to cluster on an index, a manually named index (plus a RunSQL to cluster) is the only way to cluster the database for efficiency.